# Touchpad ALPS0001 starts working after Sleep-WakeUp

Tags: manjaro, suspend, touchpad

I see a lot of questions "X doesn't working after wake up"

My problem is contrary: touchpad ALPS0001 doesn't working after boot but start working after Sleep-WakeUp.

1. System: 4.17.0-1-MANJARO, the same behaviour on 4.14-4.16 kernels.
2. `xinput list-props` after boot and after wakeup has no differences.
3. disable-enable or reattaching with xinput after boot - no results.

I don't understand how this could be possible.

Any advice where to look?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by itself with 4.18-4.19 kernels.

Kernel 4.14 - problem remains the same.

I have suspicion that problem could be solved even on 4.14 but I don't have motivation to search solution.